# Check if audio stream has loaded in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, audio, cordova, timer, loading

Is there any way to check if your audio stream has finished loading in PhoneGap? Or at least its initial buffer as with a stream it'll never finish :)

I would like to display a spinner for the user so they know their stream is loading, but at the moment I have to fake this with a JS timer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you load your media like this:

```
my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
```

You can hide the spinner in the onSuccess function

reference: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.play

Comment: Well the bizarre thing is, the Audio loads but the onSuccess function is never fired... The code I use is identical to the one you posted - happens on iOS 6